What is the deal with users with the name "Spammer"?
From time to time I see users with name "Spammer". One of the recent examples would be https://stackoverflow.com/users/19197407/spammer. And so far in my observation, they do spam.
I don't think any "normal" user would use "spammer" as their username. So is there any deal with the name? Maybe some spam-detection software doing name-and-shame?

https://chat.meta.stackexchange.com/transcript/89?m=9345840#9345840

Moderators on some Stack Exchange sites use scripts that rename user accounts to "Spammer" as part of deleting those accounts for posting spam. If the moderator does that rename network-wide, then it will affect existing profiles associated with that account on all Stack Exchange sites. So, for example, if a user has profiles on Code Golf and Stack Overflow; they post spam on Code Golf; a Code Golf moderator finds them spamming and deletes their account with a script that renames all their network profiles to "Spammer"; then you find that profile on Stack Overflow, it will have the display name "Spammer".
Another similar scenario is that the account is renamed and deleted, but then later re-created by the owner of the account. When it is re-created, it will have the old display name, which is "Spammer". (They can rename it, of course, but many spammers don't.)
Either way, your observation that "they do spam" is consistent with the known high rate of recidivism for spammers' accounts. This is why we moderators tend to destroy such accounts on sight, with steep penalties, including outright blocking of future attempts to post for up to one year.
Opinions vary on whether moderators should be renaming accounts to "Spammer" when they destroy them for spamming. The idea is to remove the spammy content that spammers often include in their display names. (In fact, I think the scripts that do the rename also clear all of the other profile information. At least, the script that I wrote [but no longer use] does this.) It's not intended as "name-and-shame".
Finally, for completeness, I should mention that it is certainly possible that a user could choose "Spammer" as their display name. It's not very likely, to be sure, but there's nothing stopping them from doing that. Stack Overflow/Stack Exchange has no requirement that display names be unique. Or good.
There is no automated spam detection system implemented by Stack Overflow/Exchange.

A moderator is able to changing a user's name is something new to me. What is more enlightening is that this ability can also affect other SE sites, which I presumed to be out of the mod's "jurisdiction".

The ability to change a user's name is frequently (or perhaps most often) used to remove a username which violates the code of conduct (profanity, slurs, etc.). In these cases changing the username is not outside the jurisdiction of the mod (as you refer to it) since the CoC applies to the network and not an individual site. @ray

"There is no automated spam detection system implemented by Stack Overflow/Exchange." This is astonishing.

"There is no automated spam detection system implemented by Stack Overflow/Exchange." This is incorrect.

Couldn't these scripts be adjusted to just replace the spammy name with user<userID>, would maybe reduce the confusion.

@RyanM No, I worded it carefully. Charcoal is not a system implemented by Stack Overflow/Exchange. It is a community-implemented system. Although I suppose you mean SpamRam, but I don't consider that to be an automated detection system. In order to work, it requires feedback that is decidedly not automated.

Yes, @Lino, that would probably be better. Clearing the user name and saving the profile should cause it to be automatically reset to that auto-generated user name. That is what I ultimately settled on in my implementation.

@CodyGray I do indeed mean SpamRam (I linked to a section specifically regarding that).  Assuming that section is correct, it is at least somewhat automated (e.g., "once it's identified spam, it feeds directly into IP blocking mechanisms").  It is at least as automated as Charcoal, which relies extensively on human input. At the very least, the distinction you're trying to draw here is misleading, as this post's phrasing makes it sound like posts go up on the site with no spam filtering. It's also not clear how one could implement an effective spam-detection system using no human feedback.

It's a moderator:
In the context of "spammer mcspamface":

[...] I was just letting you know that that specific username is almost always the direct result of a moderator renaming the account after being detected as a spammer/spam account.
- Henry Ecker, in CHQ

Or just "Spammer"

Cases of a username such as "Spammer" are almost always that a moderator on a different site made the change, but can't clean up things on other sites. Unfortunately, it's difficult for moderators to coordinate handling spammers across multiple sites, as moderators only have enhanced access on the site where they are a moderator. While the majority of cases of a "Spammer" username will be that the user actually is a spammer, there have been at least a few/several cases where a moderator on another site has made such a username change, but the user has constructive contributions on other sites. So, such a username isn't a guarantee that the content is actually bad.
- Makyen, in CHQ

